# Why does docker compose have a different behavior?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I have a NestJS project that uses TypeORM with a MySQL database.
I dockerized it using docker compose, and everything works fine on my machine (Mac).
But when I run it from my remote instance (Ubuntu 22.04) I got the following error:

```bash
server    | yarn run v1.22.19
server    | $ node dist/main
server    | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
server    |   throw err;
server    |   ^
server    | 
server    | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'
server    |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
server    |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
server    |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
server    |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
server    |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
server    |   requireStack: []
server    | }
server    | 
server    | Node.js v18.12.0
server    | error Command failed with exit code 1.
server    | info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
server exited with code 1
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS development

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy files needed for dependencies installation
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./ 

# Disable postinstall script that tries to install husky
RUN npx --quiet pinst --disable

# Install app dependencies
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

# Copy all files
COPY . .

# Increase the memory limit to be able to build
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
ENV GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

# Entrypoint command
RUN yarn build


FROM node:18-alpine AS production

# Set env to production
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy files needed for dependencies installation
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./ 

# Disable postinstall script that tries to install husky
RUN npx --quiet pinst --disable

# Install app dependencies
RUN yarn install --production --pure-lockfile

# Copy all files
COPY . .

# Copy dist folder generated in development stage
COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

# Entrypoint command
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

And here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  server:
    container_name: blognote_server
    image: bladx/blognote-server:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: production
    environment:
      RDS_HOSTNAME: ${MYSQL_HOST}
      RDS_USERNAME: ${MYSQL_USER}
      RDS_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
    command: yarn start:prod
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - blognote-network
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    links:
      - mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
  mysql:
    container_name: blognote_database
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - blognote-network
    volumes:
      - blognote_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    blognote-network:
      external: true

volumes:
  blognote_mysql_data:
```

Here is what I tried to do:

- I cleaned everything on my machine and then run `docker compose --env-file .env.docker up` but this did work.
- I run my server image using docker (not docker compose) and it did work too.
- I tried to make a snapshot then connect to it and run `node dist/main` manually, but this also worked.

So I don't know why I'm still getting this error.
And why do I have a different behavior using `docker compose` (on my remote instance)?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Your `volumes:` block is overwriting the results of the `yarn build` in the Dockerfile.  Does deleting it help?

Comment: I did fix my issue! Thanks you so much, I spent too much time on this. Do not hesitate to post it as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `docker-compose.yml` contains two lines that hide everything the image does:

```yaml
volumes:
  # Replace the image's `/usr/src/app`, including the built
  # files, with content from the host.
  - .:/usr/src/app

  # But: the `node_modules` directory is user-provided content
  # that and needs to be persisted separately from the container
  # lifecycle.  Keep that tree in an anonymous volume and never
  # update it, even if it changes in the image or the host.
  - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

You should delete this entire block.

You will see `volumes:` blocks like that that try to simulate a local-development environment in an otherwise isolated Docker container.  This will work only if the Dockerfile only `COPY`s the source code into the image without modifying it at all, and the `node_modules` library tree never changes.

In your case, the Dockerfile produces a `/usr/src/app/dist` directory in the image which may not be present on the host.  Since the first bind mount hides everything in the image's `/usr/src/app` directory, you don't get to see this built tree; and your image is directly running `node` on that built application and not trying to simulate a local development environment.  The `volumes:` don't make sense here and cause problems.